# Confusion with Ohm's law

Tags: current, resistance, ohms-law

When I connect a cell with 100 Ω resistor. voltage across circuit is 1.4 V and current is 14 mA. That means total power of cell is 1.41 x 0.014 = around 20 mW. Right?

Now if I connect two cells in series with same 100 Ω resister the volts across are 2.83 V and current is 27.6 mA

If we multiply them we get around 78 mW.

What I don't understand is if one cell has around 20 mW of power how come two cells have 78 mW instead of double of 20 mW = 40 mW maybe?

Comment: Did you measure the voltage and the current at the same time? If these were two separate measurements with the same instrument, the resistance of the current meter itself affects the measurements. The battery cell itself also has an internal resistance due to the way it is constructed, this will also affect the measurement.

Comment: upvote for using the correct term `cell` instead of battery ... you increased voltage and current, not just one ... double the resistance when two cells are used and run your calculations again

Comment: Because the power for a constant resistance increases as the square of the voltage. $$P = V \times I = V \times \frac{V}{R} = \frac {V^2}{R}$$

Comment: @MarkU yes i measure the same time.

Comment: @G35 would explain further. U mean if a cell has 1w power than 2 cells would make 4w ?

Comment: Cells (batteries) do not store any power. The cells stores Energy.

Comment: It's odd that the two cells in series produced more than 2x the voltage of one cell. If you measured the voltage with the load attached, this is a very unusual result, and suggests there might be something wrong with your measurement method.

Comment: @ThePhoton They won't be quite identical cells - one might be the 1.4V measured, the second one might be 1.43V. Depends if he measured both. The other option is its 1.415 each (his calcs say 1.41V for the first cell)

Comment: @TomCarpenter, I'd expect measurably less than the sum of the individual cell voltages, due to the internal resistance. Unless these are some big honking lantern batteries or something.

Comment: XY  problem detcted.  Please state the underlying problem you are trying to solve, not a question about your method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help :
\$P=\dfrac{U^2}{R}\$

\$P_1=\dfrac{1.41^2}{100} \approx 20\,\text{mW}\$

\$P_2=\dfrac{2.83^2}{100}\approx 80\,\text{mW}\$

Comment: Would u explain further. What is U² and why its squared. I thought power is simply equal to volt x amps

Comment: U is voltage, yes it is volt x amps, you can replace the amps with I=U/R then you get volt x amps = volts^2 / R. It's all about Ohm's law.

Comment: U is more of a nomenclature to "electric potential", which is practically synonymous to voltage.

Comment: @KingDuken It depends where do you live in where you went to school. For example: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektrische_Spannung

Comment: @KingDuken You see, U is voltage and V is potential. In your school it's V is voltage U is potential. But no matter if I say I=U/R or I=V/R I think it should be clear what I meant.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič That's interesting... I wonder why it's like that :)

Comment: Thanks friends. I just get the point. When 2 cells draw double the current and volts, the output is 4 times that of a single cell.  I was just assuming a 12v 1Ah battery runs 12ohms for 1 hour it outputs 12Wh . But two batteries in series would run 12ohms for 1 hour and output 48Wh but i didn't realized that each battery would draw 2 A so they will run for half an hour.

Comment: @Asim Please stop throwing in new things just as you are about to understand. Especially new physical quantity’s. Forget Ah and Wh and take time out of the equation.

Comment: @winny what did i say wrong?

Comment: @Marko Buršič, Your answer only shows that Asim's calculation is correct. It does not clear his confusion.

Comment: It clears my confusion (after some self thought provoking) the main point i was missing to realize was that two cells in series would draw 2x the current FROM EACH CELL than when they are separate.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the power delivered to the resistor is not limited by the power available from the cell. The power is limited by two factors:

1. the **voltage** provided by the cell
2. the **resistance** of the load

If you put two cells in series then you double the voltage. If the resistance stays the same then Ohm's Law tells us that the current must also double. So, if the voltage doubles and the current doubles, power goes up by a factor of 4.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the method to measure the max power of the cell?

Comment: To measure the **maximum** power of the cell, lower the resistance until the cell's output voltage halves. Don't do it for long though, because an equal amount of power will be dissipated inside the cell. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem

Comment: You would need to determine the equivalent series resistance of the cell. You could approach this by using small load resistor values such that the cell voltage starts falling. At the point where the cell voltage is one-half of its unloaded voltage, you are getting the maximum power from the cell...if you haven't ruined it.

Answer (score 1):

We know that **V=IR** (ohms law) .
when you added 2 cells in series then the voltage applied is doubled but the load connected(resistance) remained same. So, the **current also got doubled.**
Now, power = V*I . So, as now both current and voltage are doubled one would expect power to get four times. This was what you obtained experimentally.

Answer (score 1):

Extension/demonstration to @Marko Buršič answer:

[1] \$V={R}*{I}\$

[2] \$P={V}*{I}\$

Calculating \${I}\$ from [1]:

[3] \$I=\dfrac{V}{R}\$

Then, replacing [3] in [2]:

\$P={V}*\dfrac{V}{R}\$

Resulting:

\$P = \dfrac{V^2}{R} \$

As an addition, it could be interesting to consider the cell internal resistance which could cause a voltage drop in the cell terminals depending on the current it is sourcing

Answer (score 0):

Applying Ohm's Law, you have rightly calculated that the power dissipated by a 100Ω resistor across a 1.4V cell is 19.6mW and that dissipated by it across a 2.8V cell is 78.4mW.

The power dissipated by a load cannot not be equated to the maximum power that can be delivered by the source across which it is connected. Your confusion stems from that wrong assumption.